# include image in generated GD image

Tags: php, image, wordpress, embed, gd

Is it possible to include an external image (gif, jpg or png) into a GD generated image?

what I'm trying to do is get the latest wordpress blog post (like 5) and generate an image from it. I would like to include the title and the image uploaded with the blog post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Use one of the `imagecreatefromXXXXX` functions to import the external image into a GD image object, then use the `imagecopy` function or similar to combine it with your generated image.

For convenience, the GD function reference is [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).